# Should we use the abstracted rails polymorphic migration syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, standards

There are two ways to write a polymorphic migration in Rails. Generally, I've done this:

```
class CreateFeatures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :features do |t|
      t.integer  :featureable_id
      t.string   :featurable_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However, we can also do this:

```
class CreateFeatures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :features do |t|
      t.references  :featureable, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The two are, for all practical purposes, identical. My question: **Is one better than another? Is one better for future maintainability?**

This would likely be an issue only if one of two things changed:

1. The polymorphic abstraction version (Version #2) goes away or the syntax changes
2. The method of working a polymorphic relationship (using id and type) changes- unlikely

Just wondering if there's a preference, or if it's "Meh, doesn't really matter either way"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an all rails app, where you are generating all tables via migrations, there is no difference functionally.

Here is the code for references:

```
def references(*args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  polymorphic = options.delete(:polymorphic)
  args.each do |col|
    @base.add_column(@table_name, "#{col}_id", :integer, options)
    @base.add_column(@table_name, "#{col}_type", :string, polymorphic.is_a?(Hash) ? polymorphic : options) unless polymorphic.nil?
  end
end
```

This is all well and good but if your foreign keys on the referenced table are not _id, method one is the only choice.

references just saves you one line of code...

Comment: Yeah, what I thought. I mostly wondered if there was the *possibility* of things changing. But the more I think about it, the more that change would happen over multiple versions and deprecation– if it ever happened at all.